# Insert an english chapter in a document written in arabic

Tags: polyglossia, arabic

I want to insert in the end of a book, written in arabic using the `polyglossia` package, a chapter written in english. I try to do this, using the `\selectlanguage{english}` command, provided by this package, but its compilation with xelatex gives the following error:

`! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \MakeUppercase
{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \if@mainmatter \@cha...`

How can I do my purpose?

I give the .tex file , producing this error message:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}   %% Choose any font
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter{An english chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's obviously a bug in gloss-arabic.ldf. It "reverts" \MakeUppercase to an undefined command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\makeatletter 
 \let\orig@MakeUppercase\MakeUppercase
\makeatother 
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}   %% Choose any font
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter{An english chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A bug what can be treated I hope !

Comment: well I reported a similar issue 3 years ago and it hasn't be fixed, so I wouldn't hope to much: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/152

Comment: The problem you reported is closely the same in hebrew, yes. Thank you and hope so... these years !